# Bluemix building pending

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, pipeline

My bluemix app stuck at pending on building after pushed changes. It always shows "Queued" but it just doesn't start no matter if there are other tasks in the queue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Everything should be getting back to normal now. There was an issue in Deliver Pipeline service that was resolved.

Try again.

Comment: What was the issue? Where was it documented? How can we know this was addressed in a manner that will prevent it from happening again?  It would be more reassuring if there was some transparency. For example something along the lines of AWS explaining an outage here: https://aws.amazon.com/message/65648/

Comment: All outages are reported here: http://ibm.biz/bluemixstatus - I suggest to subscribe to RSS feed to have updates without check the page everytime.

Comment: Thanks, that's a start. Just to be clear though, as long as AWS gives me depth of explanation like this https://aws.amazon.com/message/65648/ and Bluemix provides, at best ... this: https://www.evernote.com/l/AfY7yqLGxvdJEqT3xGAGH1BJDXv1ZmSz47g .... there really is no comparison.   Transparency is key for some clients and if there is an outage that their CIO drills me about, I may need to provide a **much better answer** than "IBM says their `operations team has identified the issue and taken steps to correct it` ... and that's all we know"

Comment: Hi Mike, the team will release complete RCA for important outages. All RCA are on this site: http://incidents.ng.bluemix.net/ and linked in the status page. You can also open a ticket requesting more information and RCA. Take also note that Bluemix is based on the Open Source project Cloud Foundry. For CF bug\issue\fix I also suggest to take a look at the repository site: https://github.com/cloudfoundry

Comment: Yes, that is what I was looking for. Thank you.